# Creating hq gif from series of png with transparent background using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, png, transparency

i have series of pngs with transparent background
when i'm trying to create gif using

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i img%03d.png z.gif
```

my tranparency turns into black mess

[image: example]

what should i do to avoid this?